# Mensagem quando o usuário está saindo do aplicativo

Tags: java, android, alert

Eu sei que posso utilizar o `AlertDialog` para isso, mas sem criar botão, apenas quando o user estiver apertando o back para sair tem como aparecer uma alerta? Tipo, quando ele sai (isso envolve o sistema Android na parte que faz sozinho) seria um "finish" que o Android entende e pegando a partir dele criar argumentos para ter certeza mesmo que irá sair?

Obs.:  A intenção era para o onDestroy() interrompa o stream, somente quando estiver encerrando-a a aplicação, eu ia colocar dentro deste tipo de argumento. Para não parar quando sai apenas da classe.

Answer (score 2):

Esse tipo de abordagem não é recomendada. Primeiro porque tanto o *back button* quanto o `finish` não garantem que o app está sendo encerrado (o sistema decide se vai encerrar um app ou apenas deixá-lo em segundo plano). E segundo que você já deve tratar todos os dados que você deseja persistir no evento `onStop`.

Mas se mesmo assim quer ir por esse caminho, basta utilizar o método `onBackPressed`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  //crie seu alert
}
```

Comment: A intenção era para o onDestroy() interrompa o stream, somente quando estiver encerrando-a a aplicação, eu ia colocar dentro deste tipo de argumento. Para não parar quando sai apenas da classe.

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar a resposta do **Androiderson**, você pode fazer assim:

Na atividade principal defina o seguinte:

```
// Tratamento do back

private boolean backPressedOnce = false;
private Handler backPressedHandler = new Handler();

private static final int BACK_PRESSED_DELAY = 2000;

private final Runnable backPressedTimeoutAction = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        backPressedOnce = false;
    }
};
```

e no onBackPressed, faça o seguinte

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    // Back pressionado

    try {

            if (this.backPressedOnce) {

                // Finaliza a aplicacao

                finish();

                return;
            }

            this.backPressedOnce = true;

            Toast.makeText(this, "Pressione novamente para sair",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            backPressedHandler.postDelayed(backPressedTimeoutAction, BACK_PRESSED_DELAY);

}
```

Isto funciona assim:

- Se for na atividade principal, ao dar o back, 
  é exibido a mensagem, se der um novo back (dentro do tempo -> BACK_PRESSED_DELAY), a aplicação é encerrada
- Se trabalhares com fragmentos, necessita verificar se está no fragmento raiz para esta lógica